# Error código Call to a member function find()

Tags: php

Tengo este error en este código, como lo puedo solucionar?:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on boolean in /Users/juanpablo/Desktop/prueba-indicadores/index3.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Users/juanpablo/Desktop/prueba-indicadores/index3.php on line 5`

```html
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_html("https://widgetsdataifx.blob.core.windows.net/semana/semanaindicators");

    $valor1 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='TRM']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
    $valor2 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='BANREP']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
    $valor3 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='ICAP']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
    $valor4 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='OILVAL']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
    $valor5 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='COFFEE']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
    $valor6 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='DTF']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
    $valor7 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='UVR']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
    $valor8 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='EURCOP']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
    $valor9 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='TIB']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;

?>
```

Comment: tu código funciona, si hago echo de $valor1 me imprime: 3,120.04, esto en php 5.6 ¿que versión utilizas?

Comment: Lo estoy ejecutando desde la terminal así: `php -S localhost:8000`, y me sigue saliendo el error @patovega

Comment: lo ejecuto desde la consola php -s rutadetuarchivo.php y funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues a mí sí que me funciona, ¿has probado a descargarte de nuevo la biblioteca de http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ ? En cualquier caso, te aporto una pequeña mejora al final código para que no tengas que usar tantos echo

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html("https://widgetsdataifx.blob.core.windows.net/semana/semanaindicators");

$valor[] = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='TRM']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
$valor[] = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='BANREP']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
$valor[] = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='ICAP']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
$valor[] = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='OILVAL']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
$valor[] = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='COFFEE']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
$valor[] = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='DTF']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
$valor[] = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='UVR']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
$valor[] = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='EURCOP']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
$valor[] = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='TIB']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;

foreach($valor as $v) echo $v.'<br/>';
```

?>

Comment: Esta página no me funciona `http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/` @David

Comment: Prueba con esta a ver... https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/

Comment: Me funcionó perfecto muchas gracias. @David.

Comment: Sí, 23 archivos en 6 carpetas, supongo que el que te interesa es únicamente simple_html_dom.php, el resto será todo documentación y ejemplos. Descomprímelo todo y usa ése, que será la última versión, y ya vas probando a borrar el resto. ¡Suerte!